# How to Navigation one way around a track

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, is there anyway to tell the navigation stack to not move the robot backward?

Second, is there anyway to tell it to only go in one direction around a track instead of turning around.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225845/how-to-navigation-one-way-around-a-track/) by [trips323](https://answers.ros.org/users/24982/trips323/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the first:

I have set escape_vel of base_local_planner to 0.
Probably not the best solution but works for me.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0